# Update an array of objects (with useState hook) so that only non-repeated objects are added, while repeated objects have a quantity property increased

Tags: arrays, object, react-hooks

I have an array of objects (just showing two items as examples):

```
`const MEALS = [
  {
    id: 'm1',
    name: 'Sushi',
    description: 'Finest fish and veggies',
    price: 22.99,
  },
  {
    id: 'm2',
    name: 'Schnitzel',
    description: 'A german specialty!',
    price: 16.5,
  }, ...
]`
```

I am adding these to a new array (**order**) based on user's choice (**id**) using an onSubmit form handler:

```
`const onSubmitHandler = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const food = MEALS.filter(item => item.id === id )
    if (order.length > 0) {
      order.forEach(item => {
        if (item.id === food[0].id) {
          item.qty += qty
        } else {
          setOrder(prev => {
            return [
              ...prev,
              {
                id: food[0].id,
                name: food[0].name,
                price: food[0].price,
                qty: qty
              }
            ]
          })
        }
      })
    } else if (order.length < 1) {
      setOrder(prev => {
        return [ 
          ...prev,
          {
            id: food[0].id,
            name: food[0].name,
            price: food[0].price,
            qty: qty
          }
        ]
      })
    }
  }`
```

The above handler works. The '**qty**' value is captured by a state variable from user's input.

However, I think there could be a cleaner/succinct solution using using only one **setOrder** block and increasing an item quantity if item reoccurs in the **order** array or adding a new item if it doesn't.
I tried this and several other variations of it:

```
 `setOrder(prev => {
      prev.map(item => {
        if (item.id === food[0].id) {
          return { ...item, qty: item.qty + qty }
        }
      })
      return [
        ...prev,
        {
          id: food[0].id,
          name: food[0].name,
          price: food[0].price,
          qty: qty
        }
      ]
    })`
```

I know this is wrong as I'm returning an object to **setOrder** instead of an array. Any suggestions? I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated objects can be handled in the following way. Just give it a try with your calculation. And it's a single object solution, so there's no need to use an object array in this scenario to reduce computation.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({});
const onSubmitHandler = (e, id) => {
  let object = {
    name: foodName,
    price: foodPrice,
    qty: foodQuanity,
  };

  setValue((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [id]: object, // this creates unique key which is id basically
  }));
};
```